# show hide table on button press

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've a search form where user enters data. On search button click, if the data is found, then only display the table `tbl_paytable`  else hide it.

view page

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{action('OrderedBookController@billPay')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="row" style="padding-left: 1%;">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Bill Number</label><span class="required">*</span>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="15" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" name="NBillNumber" class="form-control"/>                                
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group"></div> 
                    <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 5%;">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>        
                    </div> 
                </div>                      
        </div>
</form>

<div id="tbl_paytable">
// display table 
</div>
```

controller block

```
public function searchBill()
    {
        return view ( 'pages.payBill');
    }

    public function billPay(Request $request)
    {
        $billNum = $request->input('NBillNumber');

        if($billNum != ""){
            $billsrch = OrderedBook::where ( 'BilledNum', $billNum )->get ();
            if (count ( $billsrch ) > 0)
            {
                return view('pages.payBill', compact('billsrch'));
            }                
            else
            {
                return view ( 'pages.payBill',compact('billsrch'))->with('alert-danger', 'Sorry No details found');
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem more clearly ?

Comment: use ajax call and show the response into the div, OR just submit the <form> and in the controller redirect back to the same blade, in the blade file use `@if (session('something')) @endif` to show the table

Answer (score 0):

$billsrch is a laravel-collection, which has a method to check if it is empty.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-isnotempty

```
@if($billsrch)
   <div id="tbl_paytable">
   // display table 
   </div>
@endif
```

Or just do the same as you did in your controller

```
@if(count($billsrch) > 0)
  <div id="tbl_paytable">
  // display table 
  </div>
@endif
```

Comment: getting error as `Undefined variable: billsrch` on `@if($billsrch->isNotEmpty())` block

Comment: that means your code : `$billsrch = OrderedBook::where ( 'BilledNum', $billNum )->get ();` returns null. i'll change my answer